# MySQL stored procedure - Problem outputting values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im trying to run the following stored procedure, however it is not giving any output.. 
If i select the values out without using the OUT parameters it works fine..

SELECT PWORD, REPLYATTR;  -- This works fine

But doing it 'correctly' doesn't for some reason, any  ideas guys?

```
DROP PROCEDURE `uuu`//

CREATE DEFINER=`auth_tracker`@`%` PROCEDURE `uuu`( IN USERNAME varchar(100), 
                                                   OUT REPLYATTR varchar(100),
                                                   OUT PWORD varchar(100) )

BEGIN

DECLARE USER_PROD_ID INTEGER; 
DECLARE ATTR VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE VAL VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN; -- Loop exit condition; set by NOT FOUND handler

DECLARE PoolHint VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE FramedIP VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL; 
DECLARE FramedRoute VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;  

-- DECLARE PWORD VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;
-- DECLARE REPLYATTR VARCHAR(100);


DECLARE cur1 CURSOR 
    FOR 
 SELECT attribute_name, value
   FROM user_product_attribute upa, product_attribute pa
  WHERE upa.product_attribute_id = pa.product_attribute_id
    AND upa.user_product_id = USER_PROD_ID;

-- Declare handler to set loop exit condition
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

-- Main logic 
SELECT upa.user_product_id
  INTO USER_PROD_ID
  FROM user_product_attribute upa, user_product up, product_attribute pa, product p
 WHERE pa.attribute_name = 'username'
   AND pa.product_attribute_id = upa.product_attribute_id
   AND pa.product_id  = p.product_id

   AND up.status      = 'active'
   AND p.product_name = 'broadband'
   AND upa.value      = USERNAME

 LIMIT 1;

  -- Open the cursor
  OPEN cur1;

  -- Start Looping
  the_loop: LOOP

  -- Get Attrib + value
  FETCH cur1
    INTO ATTR, VAL;

  -- Exit if no rows
  IF no_more_rows THEN
    CLOSE cur1;
    LEAVE the_loop;
  END IF;

  -- Grab certain vars
  IF ATTR = 'poolhint' THEN SET PoolHint := VAL; END IF;
  IF ATTR = 'Framed-IP-Address' THEN SET FramedIP := VAL; END IF;
  IF ATTR = 'Framed-Route' THEN SET FramedRoute := VAL; END IF;
  IF ATTR = 'password' THEN SET PWORD := VAL; END IF;

  -- End Loop    
  END LOOP the_loop;

-- Concat 
IF (FramedIP IS NOT NULL) THEN SET REPLYATTR := CONCAT('Framed-IP-Address=',FramedIP);
ELSEIF (PoolHint IS NOT NULL) THEN SET REPLYATTR := CONCAT('PoolHint=',PoolHint);  
END IF;

-- Add Route
IF (FramedIP IS NOT NULL AND FramedRoute IS NOT NULL) 
THEN SET REPLYATTR := CONCAT(REPLYATTR,',Framed-Route="',FramedRoute,'"');
END IF;

END//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling the procedure?

If you pass user-defined variables in when you call the proc, then you should get the output you want.

Example:

```
CALL uuu('bobby',@replyattr,@pname);
SELECT @replyattr,@pname;
```

Comment: Ok i feel stupid now... I wasnt selecting the values after calling the proc.. Thanks for the help..